# Essentials for P.SE

Tags: discussion

I was wondering if it was possible to create a "pinned" topic that has links to the best all-time questions on P.SE. My query is similar to this thread:

https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1714/the-best-of-programmers-se-1

But the difference is that instead of a weekly thread, I imagine a permanent thread that is rarely updated but has essential links. Sort of a "best of P.SE" thread that users new and old can visit to reference old topics or get answers to the most frequent questions.

Answer (score 3):

Other sites ([Super User](http://superuser.com) springs to mind) have the idea of `community-faq` questions.

These are questions tagged in some way that indicates that these are the canonical question on this topic.

Any duplicate would be closed using this as the original.

I'm not sure how we'd decide what was a good canonical question though. Sorting by votes isn't going to produce the right answer as @Jeremy's link shows.

Answer (score -1):

You mean something like this?

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes

Comment: It's telling that 46% of the proposed "essentials" are closed.

Comment: The top-voted list was brought up in the linked, related post: top voted doesn't mean it's the best of what Programmers.SE has to offer, it means it's garnered the most amount of votes for whatever reason. The purpose of these types of lists is to create *curated* collections, not to duplicate the automated question listings already available.

Comment: @Mark Trapp who would be the curator, and why wouldn't their opinions of which are the best questions reflect those of the community?

Comment: @Jeremy - And as a new user, the last thing I would think is "Hmm, this site looks cool, let me search through for the highest voted questions so I know what the most-liked threads are!" :P. On SO, there's a thread that's got 165+ votes and it's about how to simplify a boolean expression. Quantity != Quality. I think there could be a topic in meta to determine the best questions (maybe mods only, idk) and make the pinned thread.

Comment: @BlackJack It would just come down to voting on Meta as well. If you don't value the votes of the stack exchange community then I don't really see what the site can offer you.

Comment: @Jeremy - I think votes are a good representation and some of the highest voted are closed because there's nothing to add. Nonetheless, I think if you had to make a list of 10 essential thread, then taking the top10 most voted wouldn't be the best format. I think people ought to be able to discuss it.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=faq would be better -- that's interlinked posts, not just votes.